How to resolve: Not instantiable – yii\di\NotInstantiableException in azure?
I have dockerized an basic template yii2 app and I can run the docker container without any problems on localhost.
But I pushed the repository to azure. And I hit the url:
http://suitecontainer.h0gkfpg3e6gddyhe.germanywestcentral.azurecontainer.io

But then I get this error:
Not instantiable – yii\di\NotInstantiableException
Failed to instantiate component or class "yii\debug\Module".
↵
Caused by: ReflectionException
Class "yii\debug\Module" does not exist
in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php at line 507

Dockerfile looks:
FROM yiisoftware/yii2-php:8.2-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

ADD composer.lock composer.json /app/
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-dev && \
    composer clear-cache


RUN mkdir -p runtime web/assets && \
    chmod -R 775 runtime web/assets && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data runtime web/assets

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN service apache2 restart

docker-compose:
version: "3.8"
services:
  php:
    image: crisuite20backendtest.azurecr.io/web1
    container_name: yii2
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      - ./:/app:delegated
   
    ports:
      - "8000:80"

    networks:
      - yii
networks:
  yii:

And I did a composer upate.  require-dev from composer.json looks:
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.2.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/codeception": "^5.0.0 || ^4.0",
        "codeception/lib-innerbrowser": "^4.0 || ^3.0 || ^1.1",
        "codeception/module-asserts": "^3.0 || ^1.1",
        "codeception/module-yii2": "^1.1",
        "codeception/module-filesystem": "^3.0 || ^2.0 || ^1.1",
        "codeception/verify": "^3.0 || ^2.2",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^6.0 || >=2.7 <=4.2.4"
    },

index.php looks:
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

$config = require __DIR__ . '/../config/web.php';

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();


Question: how to resolve the error: Failed to instantiate component or class "yii\debug\Module". from Azure?

? Why a d-vote? What is not clear about the post?

Why it works on localhost? But not on the azure clound environment?

Class yii\debug\Module is part of yiisoft/yii2-debug package. That package is only required in your composer.json as "dev" requirement.
But in your Dockerfile you are running composer install with --no-dev option. Meaning that "dev" requirements are not being installed.
The app is then trying to load module from package that is not available.
By default Yii2 app only tries to load yii\debug\Module when it's running in debug mode. So this error usually means that you've installed packages for production (with --no-dev option) but left your app in debug mode.
To switch app from debug mode to production mode you have to remove (or comment out) following lines in web/index.php:
// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

Or, if you need to run app in debug mode in Azure remove --no-dev option in this line of your Dockerfile:
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-dev && \
    composer clear-cache


#Michal Hynčica.I edit the post. I have removed the docker image and docker container. I removed in azure the repository: web1.  I executed the command: docker push  crinternetsuite20backendtest.azurecr.io/web1:latest and still get the same error.

#Michal Hynčica.Do you have maybe other suggestions?

If it's throwing same exception even after removing debug constants than I can think only about three reasons. The app config is changed to load debug module even when the app is not in debug mode. I would need to see web.php config to tell if that's the case. The other reason might be that app is loaded from some cache so your latest changes are not actually reflected. The last option would be that you are actually explicitly using yii\debug\Module class somewhere in your code but I think that's unlikely.

#Michal Hynčica.Ah, oke. I just added the prod dsn in the web.php file. And it works now. Thank you
